# Не переведена подсказка, всплывающая при наведении курсора на ромб модератора

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Если навести курсор на ромб модератора (в ответах, изменениях, в списке вопросов и т.д.), то появится подсказка "moderator".

Должно быть "модератор" или так и задумано?

Comment: Это дефект. Отписался ребятам, спасибо!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, я тут пробежался по нескольким иностранным SO (ja,es,pt) . Ни на одном из них это не переведено.

Comment: Да, скорее всего просто не вынесли на Transifex. Ребята, кто за это дело отвечает, сейчас на каникулах. С большой вероятностью, поправим уже после праздников.

Comment: Вроде уже по-русски?

Comment: @Qwertiy, ага )